# Jquery get value from text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
 <td class="left">
      <span class="copyTarget"><?php echo $coupon['code']; ?></span>
      <a class="copyButton">[Copy code]</a>
  </td>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

**javascript code**

```
$('.copyButton').click(function() {
  var a = $('.copyTarget').text();
   alert(a);
});
```

Output results when click the button:

[image: results output when click the button]

Question: When I press the button, it will return all the value from code, for example, there are 4 value which is `promo10,yesss,promo111,zz12`. But what I want is when i click the copy code button , then only copy one code I want. How can i do that T.T ???

Comment: var a = $(this).prev().text();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** or **[`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** or **[`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** to target the related `.copyTarget` span :

```
$(this).closest('td').find('.copyTarget').text();
//or
$(this).siblings('.copyTarget').text();
//or
$(this).prev('.copyTarget').text();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.copyButton').click(function() {
   console.log( $(this).siblings('.copyTarget').text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">
      <span class="copyTarget">Code 1</span>
      <a class="copyButton">[Copy code]</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">
      <span class="copyTarget">Code 2</span>
      <a class="copyButton">[Copy code]</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">
      <span class="copyTarget">Code 3</span>
      <a class="copyButton">[Copy code]</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get the element that contains the code.

```
$(".copyButton").on("click", function(e){
    var text = $(this).siblings(".copyTarget").text();
    alert(text);
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry @jamesBond but I think there's no need for duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1):

In your click event use [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$(this).parents("td").find("span").text();
```